# Font changes and "|" (vertical bars) disappear under images

Tags: css, image, fonts

I'm having trouble with the text underneath the images on the website I'm building:

1) The "Back to home page" changes from the font it's set at (Georgia, 0.9em) to the default in Firefox. It does not do this in Safari (http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/img/modelofinteractionfull.cfm).

2) The footer appeared fine before I added images (http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/index.cfm). After I added images (inside div class=.submenu), again, the font I set (Georgia, 0.9em) changed to the default in Firefox (http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/aboutus/index.cfm).

Another issue that appear after I inserted the images:

1) The footer's vertical bars (|) disappeared between the links, in both Firefox and Safari.  You can see that the bars are actually still there when you highlight the text, but for some reason, they do not appear in white anymore so they aren't visible (http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/aboutus/index.cfm). But you can see how it's supposed to look on the home page (http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/index.cfm).

I wanted to copy my code below, but I'm having trouble understanding how to properly format it on this site, so I'll work on that. In the meantime, any thoughts?? Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Most of the examples you posted don't have ANY font set for the links

Comment: The "|"'s appear black because, again, they have no styles applied to them.

Answer (score 1):

For example, regarding question 1, the only CSS rule that sets the font family is

```
 h1,h2,p,p2,li{ /*group codes for many styles*/
   font-family:"georgia";
 }
```

It does not affect the link, since it is not inside any of those elements. Similar considerations apply to question 2. And the vertical bars are there, they are just black on black.

Use a markup validator like http://validator.w3.org to find he HTML syntax errors, fix them, and then deal with the CSS syntax errors with http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and then analyze the logical problems. Using Firefox with Firebug is a good idea, since then you can click on any element and see which, if any, CSS rules are being applied to it.

Comment: Thank you for the validator links as well!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but I suggest making sure that "Georgia" is capitalized when you declare it. I might be wrong but suspect that some browsers may not be picking up the name because it doesn't match the font's name perfectly.

Comparing the pipes (the vertical bar characters '|') between your examples shows a small flaw in the CSS. The pipes are not inside of the `<a>` tags so even if you set all your `<a>`s to white the pipes will never change. In one example ( http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/index.cfm ) the pipes are contained by a `<p2>` tag, which wasn't a valid HTML tag last I checked but that's besides the point. The `<p2>` has its color set to white which makes the pipes inside of it white. In the other example ( http://ink-12.web5test.terc.edu/aboutus/index.cfm ) the pipes are contained by a `<div>` which has its color set to black which makes the pipes black, but the `<a>`s are set to white. Since your background is also black the pipes disappear.

Answer (score 0):

For the "|" issue add the following

skeleton.css line #161

```
.footerlinks {
    padding-top: 0.5em;
    color: #fff;
}
```

For the link issue it looks to me that the font is becoming bold when you hover. You just need to define your hover state ...

fonts.css line #4

```
a:hover {
   font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: I ended up adding the color line to the outer div (#footer) but thank you, I understand better!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was such a simple fix!  I"m very new to coding (as I'm sure you could tell by the ridiculous amount of markup I had in my style sheets).  I didn't know that links could have all their own font-family, and thought that if you kept it between a heading or paragraph tag, that it would just take that on.  But I get it now, thank you!